# load multiple pages from different domain in different divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I am trying to load one or more page from different domain inside div of my page on page load. Each page will be loaded in separate div.

I can do this using jquery but I do not want to do this using javascript so that I do not have to add the jquery script as I am not using jquery in my project anywhere.

Below is the jquery code

```
$(".Widget").each(function () {   
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    $(this).load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            alert("There was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

I have the equivalent javascript code

```
var widgets = document.getElementsByClassName('Widget');
for (var i = 0, len = widgets.length; i < len; i++) {
    debugger;
    var widget = widgets[i];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        widget.innerHTML = this.response;
    };

    xhr.open('GET', widget.getAttribute("data-url"), true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

But it is displaying only one page in the last div having class `Widget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me

I have created a separate function load

```
function load(url, element) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
```

and called that function inside a for loop

```
var widgets = document.getElementsByClassName('Widget');
for(var i = 0, len = widgets.length; i < len; i++) {
    var widget = widgets[i];
    load(widget.getAttribute("data-url"),widget);
}
```